# Countifs with concat, and char to count large amounts of specific data

Tags: excel, char, concatenation, countif

So here is a tricky one that I cannot seem to get past and I'm not sure if there is even a way for it to work.  My formula is as follows:

=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$1469,CONCAT(CHAR(34),CHAR(42),LEFT(A1479,10),CHAR(42),CHAR(34)),$B$2:$B$1469,"No Card on File")

--The concat looks like this in a cell by itself
--"~Auburn~" where ~ are asterisks.

(Char34 is ", and Char42 is *)

I'm trying to create a way that I can use the concat to tell the sumifs what I'm trying to find but including the wild card and in the quotation marks in order for it to find the correct number because some of the names have added info at the end like, South Tacoma - ESD and South Tacoma - ESU.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should add the 'excel' tag

Comment: Forgot about that one, thanks

Comment: Wow, no, I hadn't thought of leaving that out pnuts, that actually worked!  Thank you!  Apparently I need more red bull lol